# Python Tkinter column stretch to window height

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an app that has multiple labels equally divided on columns

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Gui(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent

    self.initialize()

def initialize(self):
    self.grid()
    self.geometry("1000x900")
    self.attributes('-alpha', 1)

    label = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", bg="green")
    label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='EW')

    label2 = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", bg="black")
    label2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='EW')

    label3 = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", bg="red")
    label3.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='EW')

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

When running this i get the following window:
[image]

When resizing the window the labels stretch to fit the window width, but not the height.

My goal is to have N = 3 (int this example) columns that occupy the whole window and stretch accordingly when resizing the window

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldnt `sticky='NEWS'` work? But before that. Why does your `GUI` window take a `parent` as argument? Aren't `Tk` windows supposed to be a parent themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The `sticky` parameter of `grid` method is also responsible for stretching.

In `sticky` you set the edges of a grid cell – your widget will stick to these edges. If you stick to the opposite edges and then resize the window it results in stretching your widgets.

So if you would like to stretch all directions use `'nsew'` which are North, South, East and West.

```py
    label = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", bg="green")
    label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

    label2 = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", bg="black")
    label2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nsew')

    label3 = tk.Label(self, anchor="center", bg="red")
    label3.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='nsew')
```

Check this material for more: http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html#incell

Answer (score 0):

```
 sticky='NEWS'
```

insted of

```
sticky="EW"
```

did the trick